# Git: checkout without running post-checkout hook

Tags: git

I have a post-checkout hook that I like – most of the time – but from time to time I know that it would be waste of time to run it, or, since it drops and rebuilds my development database, I don't want it to do its thing.

Is there a git option that skips hooks? So fair I've struck out looking for one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think there's a command line option to do what you want, but you can trivially solve this by using an environment variable as a flag.  In your `post-checkout` script, start with:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$SKIP_POST_CHECKOUT" = 1 ] && exit 0
```

And then when you want to skip the `post-checkout` script:

```
SKIP_POST_CHECKOUT=1 git pull
```

Etc.

And you can always make your variable name shorted if that's too much to type :).

Answer (score 17):

You can do this from the command line by forcing `core.hooksPath` to be a path which does not exist (via `-c`)

for example:

```
$ cat .git/hooks/post-checkout 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'nope'
exit 1
$ git checkout -- .
nope
$ git -c core.hooksPath=/dev/null checkout -- .
$
```

Comment: via @ruediste's answer, see also https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/206#issuecomment-471169193

Answer (score 6):

I just found another [answer](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/206#issuecomment-471169193). Just add the `-c core.hooksPath=/dev/null` option to your git command. This overrides the configuration just for one command, and disables all hooks. For ecample:

```
git -c core.hooksPath=/dev/null checkout master
git -c core.hooksPath=/dev/null pull
git -c core.hooksPath=/dev/null commit ...
git -c core.hooksPath=/dev/null push
```

Comment: this is the same as the earlier answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/812183/anthony-sottile

Comment: You're right. Didn't pick up the core part when reading Sottile's answer.